# Read -ExpandProperty keys with case-insensitive

Tags: powershell, azure, scripting, azure-powershell

My following script is successfully working. But it is not reading the Tags fields with case-insensitive.

```
$resources = Get-AzureRmResource | Where-Object {($_.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines") -or ($_.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases")} |
 foreach {

   new-object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
                                    ResourceName       =       $_.ResourceName;
                                    ResourceType       =       $_.ResourceType;
                                    OperatingHours  =   
                                                        if ( ($_ | select -expand Tags).OperatingHours -ieq $null ) 
                                                        {"TAG NOT PRESENT"} 
                                                        elseif ( ($_ | select -expand Tags).OperatingHours -ieq '') 
                                                        {"NULL/EMPTY"} 
                                                        else 
                                                        {($_ | select -expand Tags).OperatingHours} ;
                                             }
          }
$resources | Format-Table
```

The Output of above script is:

```
ResourceType                        ResourceName       OperatingHours            
------------------------            --------------     ------------------            
Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines   asa-perfvm16       TAG NOT PRESENT
Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines   OAASLogicApps1     TAG NOT PRESENT
Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines   VMForPerfTest      TAG NOT PRESENT
```

Here, some resources do not have 'OperatingHours', rather they have 'operatinghours' or 'Operatinghours' or any other case-combination. This value is set by users, so it can be of any case-combination.
My above script is not fetching proper data in relation to case-insensitiveness of Tags.Key. I am not concerned with the case of Tags.Value.

I tried to modify the above script with following but still the output is same. The three resource-list that is appearing in output; all resources are created by me so I am sure that concerned Tag is present in all of them but with different cases.

Modified Script (but no success):

```
$resources = Get-AzureRmResource | Where-Object {($_.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines") -or ($_.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases")} |
 foreach {
         
        $rTags = @{}
            foreach($key in $resources.Tags.key)
            {
                      $rTags.Add($key.ToLower(), $resources.Tags[$key].ToLower())
            }

   new-object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
             ResourceName       =       $_.ResourceName;
             ResourceType       =       $_.ResourceType;
             OperatingHours =   
                  if     ( $rTags.OperatingHours -ieq $null ) 
                               {"TAG NOT PRESENT"} 
                  elseif ( $rTags.OperatingHours -ieq '') 
                               {"NULL/EMPTY"} 
                  else 
                               {$rTags.OperatingHours} ;
                                             }
          }
$resources | Format-Table
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: I don't think your problem is related on case-sensitiveness of the `OperatingHours` attribute name. PowerShell handles variable names as NOT case-sensitive -> check this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables. Maybe it helps if you change the check for attribute existense to: `[bool]($TestObject.PsObject.Properties.name -match "PropertyNameToCheck")`.

Answer (score 0):

I knew it had to be a very small change. Following is the updated script that is helping me fetch required output.

```
$resources = Get-AzureRmResource | Where-Object {($_.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines") -or ($_.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases")} |
 foreach {
            [hashtable] $rTags = @{}
            foreach($key in $_.Tags.keys)
            {
                      $rTags.Add($key.ToLower(), $_.Tags[$key].ToLower())
            }
    new-object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
                                    ResourceName    =   $_.ResourceName;
                                    ResourceType    =   $_.ResourceType;
                                    operatinghours  =   
                                                        if ( ! $rTags.ContainsKey("operatinghours") )
                                                        {"TAG NOT PRESENT"} 
                                                        elseif ( $rTags.operatinghours -ieq '' -or $rTags.operatinghours -ieq $null) 
                                                        {"NULL/EMPTY"} 
                                                        else 
                                                        {  $rTags.operatinghours } ;
                                    env             =   
                                                        if ( ! $rTags.ContainsKey("env") )
                                                        {"TAG NOT PRESENT"} 
                                                        elseif ( $rTags.env -ieq '' -or $rTags.env -ieq $null) 
                                                        {"NULL/EMPTY"} 
                                                        else 
                                                        {  $rTags.env } ;
                                             }
          }
$resources | Format-Table
```

What changes I did ?

1. Use of Hastable
2. Using **$_** rather than **$resources**  (*yeah... a very sill mistake :P*)